# How to remove proton vpn? Uninstalled it but still has vpn device on and won't let me connect to internet

Tags: vpn

[image]

Wifi works fine. Stupidly added proton vpn and then uninstalled it now every time the computer is started it shows that the pvpn is on. How to permanently remove it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be able to remove it using Network Manager -> Network properties -> VPN network and remove it from there?

Also, check if other networks are automatically using VPN upon connection and disable that setting.

Comment: Thanks, resolved a while back. so need to clear it with terminal. its a known proton VPN issue. It does not uninstall properly. Proton VPN seems to cause problem for iOS as well. Shit program.